How do i view Large BLOB (large binary object files) in flutter web?
I am using MySQL NodeJS and flutter web for my application and wanted to view a pdf in it. I don't want to use links to view the pdfs I have stored it in a large binary object format in my MySQL database
here is my code up till now
import 'package:digital_menu/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer/pdfviewer.dart';

class OwnerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OwnerPageState createState() => _OwnerPageState();
}

class _OwnerPageState extends State<OwnerPage> {
  String restaurantName = '';
  late int ownerId;
  String pdfBase64 = '';
  Uint8List? pdfBytes;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    final args =
        ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String, dynamic>;
    ownerId = args['ownerId'];
    fetchRestaurantDetails(ownerId);
  }

  Future<void> fetchRestaurantDetails(int ownerId) async {
    try {
      var url = Uri.parse(
          'http://localhost:5000/fetch_restaurant_details?ownerId=$ownerId');
      var response = await http.get(url);

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
        setState(() {
          restaurantName = data['restaurantName'];
          pdfBase64 = data['pdfBase64'];
          //print("PDF: $pdfBase64");
          pdfBytes = base64Decode(pdfBase64);
          print("pdf bytes: $pdfBytes");
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          restaurantName = 'Error fetching restaurant details';
          pdfBase64 = '';
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        restaurantName = 'Failed to connect to server';
        pdfBase64 = '';
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text('Owner ID: $ownerId'),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Text('Restaurant Name: $restaurantName'),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              if (pdfBytes != null)
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: C.baseColorDark,
                  ),
                  child: SfPdfViewer.memory(pdfBytes!),
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


i have used syncfusion flutter pdf viewer package with the following version ^26.1.38
no widget nothing is displayed on the screen

There is no sql code in the question, so mysql is not relevant from this question's point of view.
